# FileNotFoundError in Python3 (Code editor: Pycharm)

Tags: filenotfounderror

I have imported

```
import numpy as np
```

and I have used

```
xy = np.loadtxt('./Desktop/wine.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32, skiprows=1)
```

but Python3 is not able to read the file and I really do not know why. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you please include the file? It will help others to be able to properly reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is no option to upload a file according to this website [link] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386997/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-stack-overflow). However, I can pass you the link where I downloaded it from [link] (https://github.com/python-engineer/pytorchTutorial/blob/master/data/wine/wine.csv) @Justin Furuness

Answer (score 0):

Can you try again by specifying the full file path?

```
/home/username/Desktop/wine.cvs
```

Comment: I does not work either, do I need to download like a pakage for the backend. BTW I am using Ubuntu.